# Windowsless property is not working in Firefox ONLY

Tags: silverlight, windowless

I have created a simple silverlight application to display some text at realtime from xml. The text display using HTML DIV tag. I have added plugin property windowless=true, enablehtmlaccess=true,background=transparent.

On Silverlight I have added a Button "**Continue**" at Top & Bottom, which shows some message on that click.

Silverlight Plugin resize based in XML contents.

**My code :**

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button x:Name="topContinue" Content="Continue" Margin="0,30,30,0" Click="Continue_Click"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Button x:Name="bottomContinue" Content="Continue" Margin="0,0,30,30" Click="Continue_Click"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

**Creating HTML DIV on Application Start using :**

```
HtmlDocument _document = HtmlPage.Document;
HtmlElement iDIV = _document.CreateElement("DIV");
iDIV.SetAttribute("id", "divHTMLViewer");
iDIV.SetStyleAttribute("position", "absolute");
iDIV.SetStyleAttribute("z-index", "1");
iDIV.SetStyleAttribute("display", "INLINE");
iDIV.SetStyleAttribute("top", "100px");
iDIV.SetStyleAttribute("height", "0px");
iDIV.SetStyleAttribute("width", "96%");
iDIV.SetStyleAttribute("left", "15px");
iDIV.SetStyleAttribute("text-align", "justify");

HtmlElement body = _document.GetElementsByTagName("BODY")[0] as HtmlElement;
body.RemoveChild(iDIV);
body.AppendChild(iDIV);
```

**Set the XML text :**

```
HtmlElement divHTMLViewer = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("divHTMLViewer");
sText = sText.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">");
divHTMLViewer.SetStyleAttribute("display", "none");
divHTMLViewer.SetStyleAttribute("width", "96%");
divHTMLViewer.SetStyleAttribute("top", "100px");
divHTMLViewer.SetStyleAttribute("left", "15px");
divHTMLViewer.RemoveStyleAttribute("color");
divHTMLViewer.RemoveStyleAttribute("fontSize");
divHTMLViewer.SetProperty("innerHTML", sText);
divHTMLViewer.SetStyleAttribute("display", "INLINE");
setSilverlightControlHeight(UILAYOUT.INSTRUCTIONS);
```

**Silverlight Plugin size increase code :**

```
isilverlightControlHost.SetStyleAttribute("height", HtmlPage.Window.Eval("document.documentElement.scrollHeight").ToString() + "px");
isilverlightControlHost.SetStyleAttribute("position", "absolute");
```

All these code is working fine in Internet Explorer, Crome & Safari but "**Continue**" not visible in FIREFOX ONLY.

So is there any issue with this code ?

Code Sample :http://lm-bucket-for-forum-post.s3.amazonaws.com/HtMLViewerSilverLight.zip

working sample : Just replace ".zip" with "TestPage.html" in above URL.

Please let me know how can I solve it ?

Thanks in advance,
Laxmilal Menaria

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a look at your code and as I suspected its not Silverlight that seems to be the issue but more the implementation of CSS within the different browsers.

To make this work in both browsers you either need to remove the following line of code:

```
isilverlightControlHost.SetStyleAttribute("position", "absolute");
```

Or amend the code so that the position style attribute is ignored by Firefox:

```
isilverlightControlHost.SetStyleAttribute("position", "absolute !important");
```

I have tried this on my machine using IE8 and FF3.6.12 and the **Continue** buttons are visible in both when this code line is changed.